# Does Encrypted data contain White spaces?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, whitespace, card

When we encrypt any Magnetic strip data. Does that encrypted data contain spaces?
I am referring to this document [http://sagan.gae.ucm.es/~padilla/extrawork/magexam1.html](http://sagan.gae.ucm.es/%7Epadilla/extrawork/magexam1.html)
Where the card data converts into SHINTRACK1, SHINTRACK2, TRACK1 and TRACK2.
So similarly card photo will also get encrypted.
Just want to know if the encrypted data contains any white spaces.

Any supporting documents will be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

The result of the most common encryption algorithms (i.e. AES and RSA) are seemingly random binary values. It means that there is a 50% chance that a single bit is either 0 or 1. This is true for all bits of the ciphertext. 8 bits usually make up a byte.

Binary data cannot be represented as text by default, but you can still open the ciphertext in a text editor which might handle it as ASCII and see that some bytes are not printed. Others might be printed and there might even be characters in there that classify as whitespace.

Comment: To add on to this, encrypted data is typically encoded in hex/base64 ect for portability. Those can't have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your link doesn't match your question. Your link references specifically magnetic stripe data. Magnetic stripes can encode any 7-bit ASCII, which includes whitespace (and explicitly does, for example, for the cardholder's name). The encrypted format does not, because it is hex-encoded, so each character will be '0'-'F'. But the byte 0x20 (SPACE) can certainly exist in encrypted data. It probably won't, since the kind of data that's encrypted on magnetic stripes typically does not include spaces, but it certainly can.

But all of this is pointing to a fundamental problem. If you care about whitespace, you are mishandling the data. You need to follow the spec closely when decoding a magnetic stripe, and if you're worrying about whitespace, you're on the wrong road. The link you gave includes some of the ISO standards involved. What precise encoding is performed depends on which track you're reading, and thus which standard applies.